# Can anyone familiar with Metafont help me sort this out?

Tags: metafont

I tried to use Metafont to output a lowercase letter i, but the result was lamentable. It was almost as if the unit of measurement inside a character definition is different from outside.

**Regular.mf**

```
font_size 10pt#;

u#:=20/36pt#;

x_height#:=160/36pt#;
caps_height#:=260/36pt#;
descender#:=72/36pt#;

% Width of vertical stroke
stroke_width:=5/6pt#;

% First optical correction
oo#:=.1pt#;

input romanl;
```

**romanl.mf**

```
numeric dot_height;
dot_height#=(x_height#*2/3)+(caps_height#/3)+0.55*stroke_width;
beginchar("i",4u#,dot_height#,0);
    "The letter i";
    pickup pencircle xscaled stroke_width# yscaled 0.9stroke_width#;
    x1=x2=x3=.5w;
    top y1=x_height#+oo#; bot y2=-oo#;
    y3=2/3x_height#+caps_height#/3;
    
    draw z1--z2;
    pickup pencircle scaled 1.1stroke_width#;
    drawdot z3;
endchar;
```

The undesiring result:
[image: The line is too short and too thin]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1):

Just solved my own question. It seems that there are two different coordinates, and the hash symbol should not be used in the definition. Instead, I should use commands like `define_pixels` to convert properly.